# How do I spy on functions of the service I am testing?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I have an angular service with two functions, I want to test if calling function 1 with parameter 'x' calls function two.

With the below test:

```
  describe('myFunction1', function() {
    it('Should call myFunction2 if parameter is 'x'', function() {
      spyOn(myService, 'myFunction2');
      myService.myFunction1('x');
      expect(myService.myFunction2).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  });
```

My spy does not detect any changes for the function

```
function myFunction1(param) {
   if(param === 'x') {
      myFunction2();
  }
}
```

But if I change the function to the below the spy works correctly, (but the actual application breaks, so it is not a solution.

```
function myFunction1(param) {
   if(param === 'x') {
      this.myFunction2();
  }
}
```

Comment: If `myFunction1` and `myFunction2` is defined in `myService`,  `this.myFunction2();` is the correct way to call `myFunction2`, as for the breaks, maybe something go wrong in `myFunction2`, just check the browser devtools

Comment: @rubys When I debug it shows 'this' refers to myService when testing but refers to myFunction1 when the application is running, hence the break.

Comment: hmm, I've neglected that.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your full service or test file, it sounds like `myFunction2` is not a public function. 
If your service doesn't contain something like this:

```
return {
    myFunction1: myFunction1,
    myFunction2: myFunction2
};
```

...then you will have to find another way to spy on the outcome of `param === 'x'`.

Comment: Yes, both functions are exposed in the return statement.

Comment: @Michael can you post your service and test files?